# Even easiest join gets complicated in NHibernate

Tags: c#, sql, linq, nhibernate

Ok, So I have the following database schema
[image: Entity schema]

And the relation is a one-to-many relation (one Album can have many Images)

The mapping looks something like this:

```
<property name="NumID"...>
  <.../>
</property>
<set name="Images" inverse="true" cascade="delete" generic="true">
  <key>
    <column name="AlbumID" />
  </key>
  <one-to-many class="Images" />
</set>
```

And the default fetching is set to lazy

Now to the problem:
I want to load the album that holds a picture (to which I know the *NumID*)

And I would do this with the following SQL:

```
select * from Images img
join Albums alb
on alb.NumId = img.AlbumId
where img.NumID = 1026
```

But how would I do it in NHibernate? Of course I have tried in a bunch of different ways with different level of success, but nothing that is as simple as the SQL it selves.

As a aggravating factor I do need the object (Album) as a whole (or at least I need both the *NumID* and the *Name*, not lazy loaded)

I have tried this:

```
/* 1 */
var tmp1 = session.QueryOver<Images>()
   .Where(i => i.NumID == ImageID) //The ImageID is for example 1026
   .JoinQueryOver(i => i.Album)
   .Select(x => x.Album)
   .List<Album>();
// Decent to read, but this only loads the NumID from the album

/* 2 */
var tmp2 = session.Query<Images>()
    .Join(DBContext.GetQuery<Albums>(), i => i.Albums.NumID, a => a.NumID,
        (imgAlias, albAlias) => new {imgAlias, albAlias})
    .Where(x => x.imgAlias.NumID == ImageID)  //ImageID = 1026
    .Select(x => x.albAlias).ToList();
// This one actually works, but it's almost totally unreadable!
```

How is it supposed to be done?

Comment: You want ALL the images of the album you find, or only the image 1026 of the album?

Comment: @xantos No I only want to load the Album that holds the images wtih NumID = 1026

Comment: Of that album do you need any image? None, the 1026, all?

Comment: @xantos I don't need any Images, I just need the Name (and NumID)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way *(I use mostly, if not only)* - is to use **subquery** *(inner SELECT)*

```
 // subquery returning the ALBUM ID
 var sq = QueryOver.Of<Image>()
      .Where(i => i.NumID == ImageID) //The ImageID is for example 1026
      .Select(i => i.Album.Id);       // here we return the Album.ID (column AlbumID)

 // just Albums with searched Image
 var query = QueryOver.Of<Album>()
            .WithSubquery
               .WhereProperty(a => a.Id)
               .In(sq) 
            ...
            .List<Album>();
```

The biggest advantage is, that the `Album` result (SELECT) is **flat** `(not joined with multi Images)` - so we can easily use paging:

```
...
.Take(50)
.Skip(50)
.List<Album>();
```

Check some other subquery [QueryOver: select columns from subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26213519/1679310)

Comment: What is the _Of_ in the query?

Comment: Well, that is what you should be able to quickly find out in VS right? This is a **static** method which returns Detached QueryOver... (Detached criteria). These are not related to any session. They are virtual. We can build whatever query we want this way.. but at the end, we have to either bind them to session, or use them as subquery... DO check the DOC: http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#querycriteria-detachedqueries and http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover-subqueries

Comment: Ok. I got it and it seem to work. Is this the way you would solve it even if you didn't have the requirement to load the whole object?
I mean, isn't there any nicer way to write a simple join in NHibernate?

Comment: In the links I've sent you, you can find many ways.. But in general I would say *(and I DO use it this way)* : **1) many-to-one** should be joined, and even better should be projected (only columns from all joined tables are selected) **2) one-to-many** - never join. Always do filter via subqery and then play with plain/flat root object. NHibernate will load the collections ad needed. Check this: [transformer for projections](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24248309/1679310) and that [improve lazy loading](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28556429/1679310) ... Enjoy might NHibernate

Comment: Just a final question. Considering the two "rules" you gave now, how would you handle a many-to-many? Would that be a combined sq and a join?

Comment: Do you know what? try to search NHiberante many-to-many and do not use it... you will find my name everyhwere: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22563990/1679310, http://stackoverflow.com/a/16827671/1679310... so do not use many-to-many. To answer your question... it should be treated as one-to-many.. but.. (and here are even more links http://stackoverflow.com/a/21136089/1679310 to not use many to many ;)