# Selecting only certain properties from a NHibernate Subquery

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

So I have a query like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28629949/1140368):

```
var sq = QueryOver.Of<Image>()
    .Where(i => i.NumID == ImageID) //The ImageID is for example 1026
    .Select(i => i.Album.Id);       // here we return the Album.ID (column AlbumID)

// just Albums with searched Image
var query = QueryOver.Of<Album>()
    .WithSubquery
    .WhereProperty(a => a.Id)
    .In(sq) 
    .List<Album>();
```

Now let's say that my *Album* contains a large property that I don't always want to load, I only want to load the album id and name so I tried the following:

```
// just Albums with searched Image
var query = QueryOver.Of<Album>()
    .WithSubquery
    .WhereProperty(a => a.Id)
    .In(sq)
    .Select(x => new{x.Id, x.Name})
    .List<Album>();
```

But this generates me a *System.InvalidOperationException*: `variable 'x' of type 'Album' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined`

Placing the *.Select* after the *.List* does work, however then the SQL will load all of the Album, and that's just what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point would be to use NHibernate `QueryOver` method `SelectList`, instead of LINQ `Select` method

```
// .Select(x => new{x.Id, x.Name})
.SelectList(list => list
    .Select(x => x.Id)
    .Select(x => x.Name)
)
```

The `SelectList` belongs to `QueryOver` world, and will be translated into projection

And if we want to get list of `Album`, we even would need trasfromer

```
Album a = null;

...
.SelectList(list => list
    .Select(x => x.Id).WithAlias(() => a.Id)
    .Select(x => x.Name).WithAlias(() => a.Name)
)
.TransformUsing(NHibernate.Transform.Transformers.AliasToBean<Album>())
```